# Select lambda usage

Tags: c#, lambda

Sorry for perhaps noob question) but I am just trying to learn something new.
I have an array that holds object with many fields - how to 
check with select if the for example first field of this object is equal for some string ? (this field is also a string so no type ops needed)

Comment: "first" in what terms? alphabetical ordering of the variable names?

Comment: Can you show some example code? - Maybe investigate LINQ extension methods (First, Any, Where)...Select sounds like the wrong method in this respect

Comment: `array.Where(a => a.property == "my string").ToList()`

Comment: Note that [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) *transforms* your objects, I think you want [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) to *filter*.

Comment: There are many ways as many have suggested. where, select, first, firstordefault, single etc. First and single will throw error in case value is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this scenario:

```
// Some data object
public class Data {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Data(string name, int value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

// your array
Data[] array = new Data[]
{
    new Data("John Smith", 123),
    new Data("Jane Smith", 456),
    new Data("Jess Smith", 789),
    new Data("Josh Smith", 012)
}

array.Any(o => o.Name.Contains("Smith"));
// Returns true if any object's Name property contains "Smith"; otherwise, false.

array.Where(o => o.Name.StartsWith("J"));
// Returns an IEnumerable<Data> with all items in the original collection where Name starts with "J"

array.First(o => o.Name.EndsWith("Smith"));
// Returns the first Data item where the name ends with "Smith"

array.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == "John Smith");
// Returns the single element where the name is "John Smith".
// If the number of elements where the name is "John Smith" 
// is greater than 1, this will throw an exception.
// If no elements are found, this` would return null.
// (SingleOrDefault is intended for selecting unique elements).

array.Select(o => new { FullName = o.Name, Age = o.Value });
// Projects your Data[] into an IEnumerable<{FullName, Value}> 
// where {FullName, Value} is an anonymous type, Name projects to FullName and Value projects to Age.
```

Comment: Thank you for a full answer)) It is very nice to know))

Comment: @curiousity, You're welcome. Just be aware that there are a lot more LINQ extensions than I have mentioned here. You may want to research the IEnumerable<T> interface, since this is one of the foundations of LINQ. Also, intellisense documentation will help a great deal in understanding what each extension method does.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find first element in array with certain value in a field/Property, you can use LINQ FirstOrDefault:

```
var element = array.FirstOrDefault(e => e.MyField == "value");
```

This will return first element that satisfies a condition or `null`(or other default value for your type) if no such value was found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% if I understood your questing but I will try to answer it anyway:
If you want to just get the first object with the desired field you can use FirstOrDefault:

```
var element = myArray.FirstOrDefault(o => o.FirstField == "someString");
```

If the element was not found it will return null.

If you just want to check if some object in your array matches your string you can check this with any

```
bool found = myArray.Any(o => o.FirstField == "someString");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Select() is used as a projection (i.e. data transformation), not as a filter. If you want to filter a set of objects you should be looking at .Where(), Single(), First() and others. If you want to verify whether a property holds for Any or All elements in the collection, you can use those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where` clause to filter the list

```
var list = someList.Where(x => x.Name == "someName").FirstOrDefault();
var list = someList.Where(x => x.Name == "someName").ToList();
```

Use `FirstOrDefault` to select only one object and use `ToList` to select multiple objects that match a criteria defined by you.

And to make sure when comparing `strings` either compare all `UppperCase` or `LowerCase` letters.

```
var list = someList.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Equals("SOMENAME")).FirstOrDefault();
```